# How can i test if the value from mySql query is greater or less that a certain value by (a given number)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I get this query to return similar users that have a rating difference of a certain number (for example 0.5)

```
$sql = 
        "
        SELECT y.rater_id
             , GROUP_CONCAT(y.rater_id) user_id
             , GROUP_CONCAT(y.video_id) likes
             , COUNT(*) total 
          FROM rating x 
          JOIN rating y 
            ON y.video_id = x.video_id 
           AND y.rater_id <> x.rater_id 
           AND y.rate = x.rate
         WHERE x.rater_id = '$session_user_id' 
         GROUP 
            BY 'total'
            LIMIT 0 , 30; 

        ";
```

The whole point of this query is to return similar users with not much of a difference in rating a certain video (or item).

Comment: Please explain your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be enough to replace this

```
AND y.rate = x.rate
```

with this

```
AND y.rate between (x.rate - 0.5) and (x.rate + 0.5)
```

Comment: Cheers it looks right ill try that, thanks for your answer.